Gitlab with Kerberos / keytab is not readable:
I followed this documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/kerberos.html) to make gitlab work with Kerberos, but I'm getting the following error:
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/gssapi-1.3.1/lib/gssapi/simple.rb:220:in `acquire_credentials': gss_acquire_cred did not return GSS_S_COMPLETE: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (GSSAPI::GssApiError)
Keytab FILE:/etc/gitlab/test.keytab is nonexistent or empty


I checked it with this command:
gitlab-rails console require 'gssapi' gss = GSSAPI::Simple.new(nil, nil, Gitlab.config.kerberos.keytab) gss.acquire_credentials(nil)
The file is read- and writeable for the git user.
The exact version of gitlab:
System information
System:         Debian 12
Proxy:          no
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   3.2.5
Gem Version:    3.5.17
Bundler Version:2.5.11
Rake Version:   13.0.6
Redis Version:  7.0.15
Sidekiq Version:7.2.4
Go Version:     unknown

GitLab information
Version:        17.5.1-ee
Revision:       e4e13234b2d
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     PostgreSQL
DB Version:     14.11
URL:            http://gittest.tdg.biz
HTTP Clone URL: http://gittest.tdg.biz/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gittest.tdg.biz:some-group/some-project.git
Elasticsearch:  no
Geo:            no
Using LDAP:     yes
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers: kerberos

GitLab Shell
Version:        14.39.0
Repository storages:
- default:      unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket
GitLab Shell path:              /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell

Gitaly
- default Address:      unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket
- default Version:      17.5.1
- default Git Version:  2.46.2


